# How do I require an input into a textbox only if a certain checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<form>
        <label>Skills</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
        <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="Python">
        <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="C#">
        <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill4" name="skill4" value="C#">
        <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill5" name="skill5" value="C#">
        <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill6" name="skill6" value="C#">
        <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill7" name="skill7" value="C#">
        <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill8" name="skill8" value="C#">
        <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill9" name="skill9" value="C#">
        <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill10" name="skill10" value="C#">
        <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="other" value="other">
        <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <textarea id="otherbox" name="subject" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Apply">
 </form>
```

How do I make it where, if the 'other' checkbox is selected, the textbox must be filled in before you can submit the form. I know how to do this with a dropdown list of options but not checkboxes. I don't mind if the textbox is hidden until the 'other' checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the required attribute on the textarea using the checkbox value via the change event to make it reactive.

```js
const other = document.getElementById('other'),
  subject = document.getElementById('otherbox');

other.onchange = function() {
  subject.required = this.checked;
};
```

```html
<form id="suvery">
  <label>Skills</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
  <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="Python">
  <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="C#">
  <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill4" name="skill4" value="C#">
  <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill5" name="skill5" value="C#">
  <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill6" name="skill6" value="C#">
  <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill7" name="skill7" value="C#">
  <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill8" name="skill8" value="C#">
  <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill9" name="skill9" value="C#">
  <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill10" name="skill10" value="C#">
  <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="other" value="other">
  <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
  <textarea id="otherbox" name="subject" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Apply">
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason this stops my other JavaScript from working and it doesn't work itself?

Comment: You didn't put any JS snippet in your question and this code does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

here's what you can do:

```js
document.getElementById('other').onchange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.getElementById('otherbox').required = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('otherbox').required = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Skills</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
  <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="Python">
  <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="C#">
  <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill4" name="skill4" value="C#">
  <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill5" name="skill5" value="C#">
  <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill6" name="skill6" value="C#">
  <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill7" name="skill7" value="C#">
  <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill8" name="skill8" value="C#">
  <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill9" name="skill9" value="C#">
  <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="skill10" name="skill10" value="C#">
  <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="other" value="other">
  <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
  <textarea id="otherbox" name="subject" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Apply">
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason this stops my other JavaScript from working and it doesn't work itself?

Comment: `document.getElementById('otherbox').required = e.target.checked`, then the code can be reduced by removing the `if`/`else`.